# Promise inside of a Promise creates an endless loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a Promise setup to make an Http call like so (All code has been aggregated):

```
  callHttpClient({ method, endpoint, payload }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios({
        method: method,
        url: endpoint,
        data: payload,
      }).then(
        (response) => {
          if (response.status == httpStatusCodes.OK) {
            if (response.data == undefined) {
              reject(response);
            } else {
              logEventMixIn.methods.pushEvent('ApiResponse','Success', true);
              resolve(response);
            }
          }
        },
      );
    });
  },
```

The `true` flag on the `pushEvent` will trigger another call inside of the `logEventMixin.js` file which will also end up returning a Promise:

```
pushEvent(category, action, shouldLogToDatabase) {
  var payload = {
    userId: getUserId(),
    sessionKey: getSessionKey(),
    pageName: getPageName(),
    sessionId: getSessionId(),
  };

  if(shouldLogToDatabase) {

  httpHelperMixIn.methods.callEndpoint("https://pushEventEndpoint.com", payload); 
   // ** ^^ This returns a Promise ^^ **

  }

  ....
},
```

The problem is when I pass my flag as `true` to this method, I actually end up in an endless loop calling the same API endpoint thousands of times. I think it has something to do with the Promise chain, since if I place another Axios call directly in the `logEventMixin.js`, I don't get the issue anymore (like so)

```
pushEvent(category, action, shouldLogToDatabase) {
  var payload = {
    userId: getUserId(),
    sessionKey: getSessionKey(),
    pageName: getPageName(),
    sessionId: getSessionId(),
  };

  if(shouldLogToDatabase) {

  axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://pushEventEndpoint.com",
    data: payload,
  }).then((response) => {
    Promise.resolve(response);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (It's probably not the issue, but see [*What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it))

Comment: I don't see anything here that would be causing it, it's likely to be further up the call stack, i.e. whatever is calling `pushEvent`

Comment: @andymccullough My callstack would be something like so:

 `httpHelperMixIn.methods.callEndpoint()` --> returns the Promise from `callHttpClient` ie the `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...`

Comment: In order to loop, there must either be a looping construct like `while(somethingAlwaysTrue)`, or a recursion: like A calls A, or (the pernicious kind you probably have) an indirect recursion, where A calls B calls C calls A.  The functions in the OP code don't refer to each other at all.  The only thing visible in the code is an ill-advised promise wrapping a promise.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess, I'd say that `httpHelperMixIn.methods.callEndpoint` is making some other API call (wager: for auth) which indirectly circles back on `pushEvent`.  Step through, or console log at the top of methods and you might find a cycle.

Comment: @danh `callEndpoint` calls `callHttpClient()` which then calls `pushEvent()`

Comment: More specifically because this is a Vue app. CallEndpoint calls `store.dispatch()` (Vuex) which returns  `callHttpClient()` which returns the promise all the back up the chain (presumably).

Comment: I didn't see the pushEvent in callHttpClient!  Isn't that the answer?  callEndpoint calls callHttpClient() which then calls pushEvent() WHICH THEN CALLS callEndpoint (forgive the caps :-)) isn't that it?

Comment: Yes! I guess now the question is how do I do this without the infinite loop so that all Promises resolve?

Comment: So the cycle is this: call an api, then call an api to log the completion of the api, then call to log the completion of that last one, and so on.  That's what we must fix.  `logEventMixIn.methods.pushEvent('ApiResponse','Success', **false**);` might do it, but this is a logic problem, not a promise problem. (though, to repeat, the code's use of promises is ill-advised and should also be fixed)

Comment: @danh Right, exactly what I was thinking (using a bool). what is your advice on the Promise to fix it?

Comment: @845614720 - posted a summary of the logic issue and a suggestion about promise style, with a sort of hand wave at error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not handling the Promise fully, try -

```
callHttpClient({ method, endpoint, payload }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios({
        method: method,
        url: endpoint,
        data: payload,
      }).then(
        (response) => {
          if (response.status == httpStatusCodes.OK) {
            if (response.data == undefined) {
              reject(response);
            } else {
              logEventMixIn.methods.pushEvent('ApiResponse','Success', true).then(() => {
                 resolve(response); // <!-- you should be resolving only when `pushEvent` resolves
              });
              
            }
          }
        },
      );
    });
  },
```

and also -

```
pushEvent(category, action, shouldLogToDatabase) {
  var payload = {
    userId: getUserId(),
    sessionKey: getSessionKey(),
    pageName: getPageName(),
    sessionId: getSessionId(),
  };

  if(shouldLogToDatabase) {
     return httpHelperMixIn.methods.callEndpoint("https://pushEventEndpoint.com", payload); 
   // you need to return the above Promise....
  }

  // also return a Promise here for your other code...
  ....
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only problem here is that I don't care about the response of the Promise from `return httpHelperMixIn.methods.callEndpoint("https://pushEventEndpoint.com", payload); `. It's a logging call that is meant to be just fire and forget.

Answer (score 0):

We've determined in comments that the source of the loop is indirect recursion, wherein the making a remote call to log a successful remote call generates a loop. The fix is to not log the logs.

The issues with promise code are mostly stylistic, but important because at minimum they obscure the bugs.  The following is roughly equivalent to the OP code, but more concise and stylistically correct...

```
async callHttpClient({ method, endpoint, payload }) {
  const response = await axios({
    method: method,
    url: endpoint,
    data: payload,
  });
  logEventMixIn.methods.pushEvent('ApiResponse','Success', false); // "fire and forget" don't await, and don't log the log
  return response;
}

async pushEvent(category, action, shouldLogToDatabase) {
  var payload = {
    userId: getUserId(),
    sessionKey: getSessionKey(),
    pageName: getPageName(),
    sessionId: getSessionId(),
  };

  if (shouldLogToDatabase) {
    return httpHelperMixIn.methods.callEndpoint("https://pushEventEndpoint.com", payload); 
  } else {
    // do something else with payload
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

Note that it makes no mention of error handling. The OP code doesn't either, but that shortcoming is disguised in the OP code with the presence of a `reject` here or there.

The better pattern on error handling is to throw when an error is found, and catch when something can be done about it, generally earlier in the call chain.